# How many divisors of $n$ are less than or equal to $m$?

Tags: number-theory, factoring

Can I calc it in less than $O(\sqrt{n})$ time?

Comment: Is $n \gt m^2$?

Comment: What do you mean by *less than $O(\sqrt{n})$*? The latter expression already has a meaning of upper bound.

Comment: @ftfish I hope for a algorithm has a better bound.

Comment: @Henry It's not necessary.

Comment: @TangXianghao: If $m=2$ and $n$ is large then you can do the calculation rather faster than  $O(\sqrt{n})$

Comment: You can factor $n$ in better than $O(\sqrt n)$ and then check all of the divisors.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm:

1. Factorize $n$ using any sub-exponential (in term of the binary length of $n$) algorithm, e.g. [General number field sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve).
2. According to asymptotics of the [Divisor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Approximate_growth_rate), the number of divisors of $n$ is sub-exponential. So just run through the list of all its divisors and compare with $m$.

Since both steps take sub-exponential time, the overall run time will be sub-exponential, and thus in $o(\sqrt{n})$ ([little-o notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Oh#Little-o_notation)).